# CSS Linear Gradient Showing wrong word

Tags: html, css

My website is http://tracebaxter.com and I have a linear gradient mimicking the titles acting as text shadow. Every time I first load the page,all the gradients are using the last title and I have to reload the page for it to be right. What is causing this.
My CSS

```css
h2,h2:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  }
.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.header {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #4d4235;
  font-family: 'Righteous', serif;
  font-size: 6em;
  text-shadow: .03em .03em 0 gray;
  width: 100%;
  }
  h2:after {
    content: attr(data-shadow);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: .06em; left: .06em;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-image:
      -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, transparent 0%, transparent 25%, #555 25%, #555 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #555 75%);
    background-size: .05em .05em;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

    animation: shad-anim 12s linear infinite;
    }
@keyframes shad-anim {
  0% {background-position: 0 0}
  0% {background-position: 100% -100%}
  }
```

```html
<h2 id="about" class="dashed-shadow" data-shadow="About">About</h2>
```

Comment: What do you mean they are using the last title? All the gradients match the text when I load it, including the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is not a browser-specific issue? This code appears to work as advertised to me, generating an animated text-shadow.

Note that 'webkit-' properties are non-standard. You could use the standards-compliant equivalents:

`color` instead of `webkit-fill-color`

Add `background-clip` same as the `webkit-background-clip`

Note also that `background-clip: text` and `webkit-fill-color` are currently not supported by the last version of the two microsoft browsers: IE or Edge. You may need to provide a fallback. It still looks okay because the second text is generated as a shadow, if a little dark.

Comment: Thanks for the response, its been bugging me all day.  I would pull up the site and behind all my titles the gradient for in progress would show up until I reloaded the page, but soon after I posted this it stopped! The tips are awesome though I will implement them.